# Can I reuse crystal frequency of Arduino?

Tags: oscillator-clock

If I use some IC which requires clock frequency like 16MHz, can I take one from Arduino?

Or this it too high frequency to travel to neighboring board?

Comment: Set the CKOUT fuse to 1, will give you the clock output. And you have to set PORTB0 to an output (`pinMode(8,OUTPUT);`). You probably don't want to use to long of a trace/wire.

Comment: The expense of properly sending a clock off-board will be greater than generating a new one over there, so only do it if your signals must be synchronized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arduino constant clock output](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16698/arduino-constant-clock-output)

Comment: am dividing arduino clock frequency from 16Mhz to 8Mhz but am getting spike in clock signal how can i reduce that

Answer (score 1):

The frequency is important. Make sure they are the same or it will probably not work.

Answer (score -1):

Yes but you need to know what you are doing.  You will need a clock driver and possibly a clock receiver depending on the devices you select.  Then you need to modify both boards voiding any possible warranty.

The best answer is NO!

Comment: I don't agree with that. I don't see any problem with using the arduino clock to clock another chip. The whole point of buying an Arduino is experiment and learn! Screw the warranty. I personally have done it often. Its not that hard.

Comment: I disagree. Why is it necessary to change the board given Gerben's comment? And I dunno understand, why you are referencing to warranty. Nobody will reasonably try to claim a warranty for a 15€ device where a failure is almost always user generated. If someone over here ever has successfully claimed a warranty for an arduino, let him now speak...

Comment: Why not download this application from TI: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scaa082a/scaa082a.pdf Then download: https://www.elprocus.com/crystal-oscillator-circuit-and-working/ after you read them and understand them you will know why I answered as I did. Note this is an open ended question without the necessary specifics to do a proper design. Your solution may work but what happens if yo build thousands of them?