# Cheat Sheet for interruption

Tags: arduino-uno

Just read a post about timers and there was a timers cheat sheet posted there. It has been very helpful and I wonder if there is one for interrupts as well?

The post with the nice timer cheatsheet was this one [Arduino constant clock output](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16698/arduino-constant-clock-output)

Comment: Wouldn't make much sense. Must peripherals can generate interrupts, and each has it's own semantics. An interrupt cheat sheet would have to cover the workings of most of the MCU peripherals: to much material for a “cheat sheet” format.

Comment: The "cheat sheet" is more commonly known as [the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this (for the Arduino Uno based MPU): [image]

Comment: The question was tagged “arduino-uno”, and this table _does not_ apply to the Uno. You should at least tell in the answer what processor it is for.

Comment: Oops. You're correct. My apology. Let me edit that right now.